# processing.js loadImage()

Tags: image, processing.js

I've made a processing.js webpage that i'm using to put a platformer game on, so i've got the code already planned out. Now I just have to put it on a webpage. Right now I can make the background red, but when I went to put the code in, I realised that it was't drawing any images. I looked it up, and the image method processing.js uses is very different to what I was doing. It still won't work.

Here is my processing.js code inside the HelloWeb.pde file:

```java
    preload = 
"file:///E:/Extra%20Curricular/STEM%20Videogame/Art/BlackKingIdle.png";
```

//note that the E drive is my USB. I don't know if it will have an effect?

```java
    //AI Codes
    int wolfX = 310;
    int wolfY = 200;
    int wolfHealth = 50;

    //Health
    int kingHealth = 100;
    int dragon = 500;

    //LV design
    int floorHeight = 300;
    int lvlNum = 1;

    //movement (x)
    int maxSpeed = 6.25; 
    int xForce = 0;
    int kingXPos = 947.5;

    //movement (y)
    int kingYPos = floorHeight + 50;
    int yForce = -15;
    int jumping = false;


    void setup() {
        size(1895, 800);
        background(255, 0, 0);
    }

    void draw() {
        if (lvlNum != 0) {
         PImage kingIdle = loadImage("file:///E:/Extra%20Curricular/STEM%20Videogame/Art/BlackKingIdle.png")
      }
    };
```

And the HTML:

```java
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Hello Web - Processing.js Test</title>
      <script src="processing.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Processing.js Test</h1>
      <p>This is my first Processing.js web-based sketch:</p>
     <canvas data-processing-sources="HelloWeb.pde" width="1895" height="800" style="border:4px solid"></canvas>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get into the habit of posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try to narrow your problem down to as few lines as possible. For example this code demonstrates your problem:

```java
/* @pjs preload="C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\August 1, 2016\\cropped\\Sky4.JPG"; */
PImage myImage;

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
  myImage = loadImage("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\August 1, 2016\\cropped\\Sky4.JPG");
}

void draw(){
  image(myImage, 50,50, 100,100);
}
```

You should also get into the habit of checking out your JavaScript console. There you'll see any errors you're getting. If you look there, you should see an error that says `"(index):1 Not allowed to load local resource"`.

And that error says it all. You aren't allowed to access local files from a webpage, even if you're running that webpage locally.

Your Processing.js webpage is being served by a local webserver. Processing handles this for you, which is nice, but that webserver can only touch files that you've imported into your sketch directory. Do this through the sketch menu in the Processing editor, or you can manually add a `data` folder to your sketch directory, and then put your images in there. Then just refer to the images relative to the sketch.

Two lines in my example code would change:

```java
/* @pjs preload="Sky4.JPG"; */
myImage = loadImage("Sky4.JPG");
```

If you don't want to put your images in your sketch directory, then you're going to have to use your own webserver. You can run one locally, or you can upload your images to an image host and use the url in your code.

Comment: @Marco No problem. Note that you can accept (and upvote) answers that help you. Looking at your question history, it looks like you haven't accepted any answers.